# Using only Pagerfanta helpers with Symfony 2 and Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, pagerfanta

I have an application that consumes a webservice. My app send request to webservice like this:

Request example:

`https://mywebservice.com/interesting-route/?page=4&limit=30`

So I receive just a slice of result, not the complete array, else I could use ArrayAdapter to paginate in my controller. I wanna use just the twig extension to generate DOM elements in my views.

Response example:

```js
{
  results:
    [
      {
        title: 'Nice title',
        body: 'Nice body'
      },
      ...,
      {
        title: 'Nice title',
        body: 'Nice body'
      },
    ],
  total: 1350,
  limit: 30
]
```

What's the way, maybe using FixedAdapter?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need Pagerfanta to manipulate the results (if already managed by webservice) but create a DOM elements paginator with this data (current page and total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the `FixedAdapter` should do what you need here.  Here's some sample controller code you could adapt:

```php
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $page = 1;
    if ($request->get('page') !== null) {
        $page = $request->get('page');
    }
    $totalResults = // call your webservice to get a total
    $limit = 30;

    $slice = $this->callMyWebserviceInterestingRoute($page, $limit);

    $adapter = new FixedAdapter($totalResults, $slice);
    $pagerfanta = new Pagerfanta($adapter);
    $pagerfanta->setMaxPerPage($limit);
    $pagerfanta->setCurrentPage($page);

    return $this->render('default/pages.html.twig', [
        'my_pager' => $pagerfanta,
    ]);
}
```

Hope this helps.